# Haw can i use a value from a session variable within the attribute of a control?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, session-variables

I have an ASP control custom built and I need to pass a value taken from a session variable to it like so:

```
<custom:control id='mycontrol' value="+Session['myControlValue']+">
   ...
</custom:control>
```

the above code obviously doesn't work, I need a way to insert the Session value in the control in this way somehow, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a data bound control you may try this:

```
<custom:control id="mycontrol" 
                runat="server" 
                value='<%# Session["myControlValue"] %>'>
</custom:control>
```

Personally I would prefer setting this value from the code behind. It seems a little strange to me that a view (aspx) page manipulates the session:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    mycontrol.Value = Session["myControlValue"];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestin but it doesn't seem to work, its just sending  the literal string '<%# Session["mycontrolvalue"] %>' to the control instead of working out what Session["mycontrolvalue"] actually is

Comment: Williams comment are correct.. (even if you want i.e. a public static property from the code file).

Answer (score 0):

Switch the quotes, like so:

```
<custom:control id="mycontrol" 
            runat="server" 
            value='<%# Session["myControlValue"] %>' />
```

Comment: Is there a reason for doing so?  Or is it just the syntax rules of the quotes / parsing?